# Django - How to listen response before sending it? DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF for creating the APIs. It automatically sends the validates the input data, apply CRUD operations and then send the response. I want to update the response format. Such for eg:- to `GET` all users, the response send by DRF is a `list` of user details. I want something like this:-

```
{
'response':[{}, {}],
'status': 200
}
```

How and where can I listen to response for every API and customize the response before sending it back to the client.

I've found something similar for `custom_exceptions`. Is there something similar for normal responses.

Answer (score 0):

I made a python monkey patch in `my_http.py`

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import response


class Response(JsonResponse):
    def __init__(self, data={}, errors=[], status=200, success=True, headers={}, **kwargs):
        if status > 309:
            success = False
        # Custom response format here
        data = dict(data=data, errors=errors, status=status, success=success)
        super(Response, self).__init__(data, status=status, **kwargs)
        if headers:
            for key, value in headers.items():
                self[key] = value

# Overwrite default rest_framework Response
response.Response = Response
```

In `my_app/__init__.py`, add an app config `default_app_config = "my_app.apps.MyAppConfig"` to make sure patch will be used.

This is `MyAppConfig` code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        from my_http import Response  # noqa
```

In view, I used `from my_http import Response`

Comment: That's great!! However, I'm using `DRF Mixins`, and hence I dont use `Response`. There should be some middleware, not sure though, that will receive the response and alter the response accordingly.

Comment: That patch will overwrite default DRF `rest_framework.response.Response` and you can use any `DRF Mixins` with your response format.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#using-generic-class-based-views. Where shall I use this `patch` Response?

Comment: Just add that patch, I also update answer to make patch affect on your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom `JSONRenderer` that returns data in that format.

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer


class CustomJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        response = renderer_context['response']
        ret = super(CustomJSONRenderer, self).render(
                 data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None)

        return """{{
            response: {},
            status: {}
        }}""".format(
            ret.decode(), response.status_code
        ).encode()
```

You can set `CustomJSONRenderer` as the global default for your response in settings. More options including [setting this for individual views or viewsets.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'api_fonda.renderers.CustomJSONRenderer',
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct way. However, it throws up an error  while returning `AssertionError: renderer returned unicode, and did not specify a charset value.`

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast You may need to decode from bytes to unicode then back. See updated answer. In any case, your renderer should return a `bytes` object.